# Installing Ubuntu on a laptop with FreeDOS

Tags: boot, system-installation, hp

I have no programming knowledge whatsoever. I accidentally bought a laptop that only has FreeDOS on it. I have decided to have a go at installing Ubuntu on this.

I have looked at video and written tutorials, but it seems that I am missing something. On a different computer, I downloaded Ubuntu ISO file (as a FAT32) on to the desktop, then transferred it  along with the file folder across to the pen drive along with the universal file installer 1.9.8.0.

Next I turned on my HP laptop, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> repeatedly during boot. This now gave me the option of booting the computer from the pen drive, but this is where it goes wrong. Unlike the videos and blogs, Ubuntu does not show up, it reverts back to dos.

Anyone help a novice please?

Comment: an ISO file is a disk image. you have to "burn" the image to the pen drive not copy the file over.

Comment: So, opened ISO viewer , then asked it to burn, but only gave me option of burning to DVD drive, not USB

Comment: see the linked answer for directions on "burning" to a USB.

Answer (score 0):

May be the usb drive not correctly installed on usb. Check in other computer if starts the ubuntu of the pen. If no starts try to use other program (Windisk32, yumy, unebootin) to do de image or change de usb pen.

If starts in other computer. Try to change de usb conector where you plug the pen.

Comment: No. USB is fine and recognised by windows . Just no option in ISO viewer to burn other than to DVD drive

Comment: managed to burn to DVD instead, inserted in new laptop. Hopefully seems to be installing. Fingers crossed. Thnx all for help